# JQuery - Click, disable mouseover with reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a tooltip that popups away from the image. However, I cannot seem to get clicking working concurrently with hovering. What I'd like to achieve is to have the popup stay visible when the user clicks the image and disable it when the user clicks outside the popup box, however, it would be visible if the user has the hovers in the image and hidden when the user hovers out of the image. I'm not quite sure how to tackle this.

http://jsfiddle.net/BZ4M7/

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="description"> Here is the big fat description box</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    border: 1px #333 solid;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-image:url('http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/sqtripic.gif');
}
.description {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%
    background: #000000;
}
```

JS

```
$(".tooltip").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".description").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".description").hide();
});

var isShown;
$(".tooltip").mousedown(function() {
    if (isShown == false){
        $(this).children(".description").show();
        isShown = true;
    }
}).mousedown(function() {
    if (isShown == true){
        $(this).children(".description").hide();
        isShown = false;
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)
Thanks!

Comment: Ever think of `e.preventDefaults` or `e.stopPropigation()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the following additions/changes to your CSS:

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
}
.description {
    left: 102%;
}
```

and the following changes to your JS/jQuery:

```
$(".tooltip").mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(this).children(".description").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    if (isShown === false) {
        $(this).children(".description").hide();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

isShown = false;
$(".tooltip").click(function (e) {
    if (isShown === true) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.description').hide();
        isShown = false;
    } else {
        $(this).children('.description').show();
        isShown = true;
    }
});
```

I think this accomplishes what you're after, except hiding `.description` by click outside of `.tooltip`. There ISN'T anything there to click on at the moment.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BZ4M7/1/

Comment: I can work with this and expand on it but is there a way to get the description box always on top of any image box? http://jsfiddle.net/BZ4M7/3/

Comment: Like this maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/BZ4M7/4/. I set the `z-index` to 1 instead of -1.

Comment: Oops. Not sure why I didn't catch that. Thank you for that. When you click, is there anyway you can limit to one description box being permanently shown at any given point? I created a counter and if statements, but my failed attempt doesn't solve that problem. http://jsfiddle.net/BZ4M7/5/